# Sas macro send email

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Hi I am trying to send mail from sas EG with macro. Please I have two questions:

1. This code generates an error: "There is no matching `%DO` statement
   froe the `%END`. This statement will ignore"
2. How can I change the HTML output style?

   ```
   %macro desicion;
      %if &dsempty=0 %then %do
         filename outbox email
         to=('smdy@mail.com')

         type='text/html'
         subject='Achtung!'
         from=('Robot@sender');

         ods html body=outbox rs=none;

         proc report data=work.final1 style=Analisis;
         run;

         ods html close;    
      %end;
   %mend;
   ```

Comment: 1) you forgot the `;` after the %do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) you forgot the `;` after the %do

```
%macro desicion;
%if &dsempty=0 %then %do;
               filename outbox email
               to=('smdy@mail.com')

               type='text/html'
               subject='Achtung!'
               from=('Robot@sender');

      ods html body=outbox rs=none;

      proc report data=work.final1 style=Analisis;
      run;

      ods html close;

%end;
%mend;
```

2) That questions is a bit broad.

You can apply a template style but that's doesn't always give the desired results.
What I do is build a full html email with integrated css like this

```
    data _null_;
        file mymail;
        set DS end=eof;

        if _n_=1 then do;
            put '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">';
            put '<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">';
            put '<head>';
            put '  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />';
            put '  <title>TITLE</title>';
            put '  <style type="text/css">';
            put '    .row{width:100%;} ';
            put '    body {margin:0; padding:0;} ';
            ...
```

EDIT: Here is link with more explanation on this method (cf. page 3)
http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/060-2010.pdf

Comment: Could you explain the method you sugest. I find some information about it, but I did not find the method to insert data set in html code. I tried yours but email is blank? What means  5 and 6 rows in your code?  Thank you

Comment: I update my answer. I followed instructions in this link, page 3 : http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings10/060-2010.pdf

Comment: thanks! One more question I am trying to sen EMAIL from sas EG and am using "preimage" command. Is it possible to build in picture right in email (not a link). I need it to everyone can see it.

Comment: I don't know `premimage`. What I would do is host the image on a server and insert it in the email with html `<img src="link to server">`. Or you could send it in attachment probably.

Comment: Image  on the server is not suitable cause someone could have not access to it. Attach too. Is a logo of a company, I want it to be on the board of the letter. Is there is any way to do it?

Comment: If it's on a public server, everyone will be able to access it. Just upload your image to an image hosting service.